# Servidor Spring no inicia cuando le aplico SSL

Tags: ssl, bitbucket

Estoy montando un servidor GIT de Bitbucket el cual esta basado en tomcat y Spring

Cuando le activo el SSL el servidor no inicia y da errores.

Tengo el archivo bitbucket.properties editado de la siguiente forma:

```
server.port=8443
server.scheme=https
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store= /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/config/ssl-keystore/key.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-password=clave
server.ssl.key-password=clave
#server.ssl.keyAlias= tomcat
```

Este es el log

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)


2019-07-01 12:37:52,012 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.b.BitbucketServerApplication Starting BitbucketServerApplication on srvgitcl01 with PID 18899 (/opt/atlassian/b2.3/app/WEB-INF/classes started by atlbitbucket in /)
2019-07-01 12:37:52,026 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.b.BitbucketServerApplication No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-01 12:37:57,879 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.boot.log.BuildInfoLogger Starting Bitbucket 6.2.3 (a254062 built on Wed Jun 05 07:35:39 UTC 2019)
2019-07-01 12:37:57,886 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.boot.log.BuildInfoLogger JVM: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_172-b11
2019-07-01 12:38:09,238 ERROR [main]  o.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.boot.BitbucketServerApplication.start(BitbucketServerApplication.java:247)
        at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.boot.BitbucketServerApplication.main(BitbucketServerApplication.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.launcher.BitbucketServerLauncher.start(BitbucketServerLauncher.java:151)
        at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.launcher.BitbucketServerLauncher.main(BitbucketServerLauncher.java:99)
        ... 6 frames trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:317)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
2019-07-01 12:38:13,955 ERROR [spring-startup]  c.a.j.s.w.s.JohnsonDispatcherServlet SpringMVC dispatcher [springMvc] could not be started
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/opt/atlassian/bitbucket/6.2.3/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/atlassian/stash/internal/config/OsgiComponentsWiring.class]; nested exception is java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:518)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        ... 21 frames trimmed
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException: null
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:164)
        at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
        at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readStream(ClassReader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:273)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
2019-07-01 12:38:14,680 WARN  [main]  o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [InterruptTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
2019-07-01 12:38:14,805 ERROR [main]  o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-07-01 12:38:14,827 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.boot.log.BuildInfoLogger Bitbucket 6.2.3 has shut down
```

Me arroja este error principal:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
```

El cual supongo que es la razon por la que el servidor no se incia.

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
```

Que puede ser el error por el cual se esta cayendo el inicio?
El certificado que tengo es en formato pfx perteneciente a Microsoft, y me fue dado para implementarlo en bitbucket, no lo genere yo.

Como podria hacer para lograr que inicie?, Acaso es incompatible con pfx?, debo convertirlo a otros formatos?.

Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Tenes que extraer el certificado y la clave privada del pfx e incluirlos en un keystore. Cuando hagas eso, también vas a tener disponible el property de "alias". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217107/how-to-convert-pfx-file-to-keystore-with-private-key

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, con el comando siguiente extraje el jks del archivo pfx

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mypfxfile.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 
-destkeystore clientcert.jks -deststoretype JKS

Con este otro comando logre dar con el alias que finalmente es un numero hexadecimal larguisimo, como 30 dig.

 keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore your_pfx_file -v | grep Alias

El tema es que no entiendo muy bien eso de ponerlos en un keystore.

Tambien baje un software llamado Keystore Explorer, no se si sea mas facil desde ahi.

Como funciona el procedimiento??

Comment: Cuando ejecutes el comando: keytool -list -keystore clientcert.jks, el alias es el nombre que tiene la entrada al principio. Por ejemplo en esta lína: `akeyname, 01/07/2019, PrivateKeyEntry,
Huella Digital de Certificado (SHA1): 24:4C:2B:84:0F:F1:20:9C:C5:47:B9:6F:38:D3:27:5C:EE:78:C9:3D` el alias es "akeyname". (Por las dudas el keystore que tenes que usar con la aplicación es el jks, no el pkcs12).

Comment: Exacto, muchas gracias, no me habia funcionado asi que cambie el keystore type por  jks. Curiosamente al crear el jks me pidio una nueva contraseña y tuve que poner una distinta a la original por asuntos de largo.
Al momento de colocar las contraseñas en el properties:

server.ssl.key-store-password=xxxxx. (tuve que poner la nueva clave del jks)
server.ssl.key-password=yyyyy (conserve la clave del pfx).

No se por que ocurre esto, pero asi me funciono, ya que si ponia en ambos lados la nueva password o la original del pfx no me arrancaba.

Comment: Por ahi te mareaste en algún lado. El key store que estás usando es el jks. El pfx ya no lo usas, al menos no para la aplicación. Y hay dos claves: una clave que es del key store y luego otra para la entrada porpia de la clave privada. Debieran ser distintas, pero nada implide que sean iguales.

Comment: Claro, cambie el tipo de clave a jks,y en las claves estoy usando la generada al momento de crear el jks, y la otra original que venia desde pfx, aunque no lo este usando. Funciona perfecto y esta verificado el el ssl, pero solo si entro por el dns, si entro por la ip directa no me lo verifica, ademas que de aun me falta hacer la redireccion automatica de http a https para no tener que poner https a mano. Son ajustes ya menores pero estoy averiguando como se hace , por ahi lei que se hace con nginx.
Saludos Juan!